# How to display an image when button is pressed in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to display an UIImageView when a button is pressed. In my main story board, I have an ImageView(hidden) and an UIButton. How do I modify the ViewController to make that happen?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var ImageView: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        ImageView.image = UIImage(named: "18.pic_hd.jpg")
    }
}
```

This is  what I currently have so far, but the program breaks and gives me Thread 1: signal SIGABRT. I am new to Xcode and Swift, so any direction is appreciated!

Comment: Be sure you have connected ImageView outlet in your storyboard. Outlets provide a way to reference the objects you added to your storyboard from source code files. To create an outlet, Control-drag from a particular object in your storyboard to a view controller file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should drag and drop `UIButton` from storyBoard to your code and use `Action` to have an `IBAction` in your viewController.

After that use `imageView.isHidden = false` to show the image and vice versa.

sample code:

```
   import UIKit

   class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var imageView: UIImageView!
    @IBAction func someButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
       // when button tapped this code will execute
       imageView.isHidden = false
     }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        imageView.isHidden = true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
ImageView.isHidden = true
```

to hide your image, and

```
ImageView.isHidden = false
```

to show it.
add an IBAction to your button to do this.